# Why sometimes the coefficients fitted by R function "lm" differs a lot from that by "glmnet" with lambda=0?

Tags: r, regression, lm, glmnet, lasso-regression

I encountered a weird case where `lm` and `glmnet` with lambda=0 produced different results on the same data.

The calls of the two functions are like:

```
# linear regression
fit <- lm(y ~ X - 1)

# lasso regression with lambda=0
fit <- glmnet::glmnet(X, y, intercept=FALSE, alpha=1, lambda=0)
```

The summary of `lm` fitted objects:

```
Call:
lm(formula = working_yj ~ working_xj - 1)

Residuals:
       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
-2.250e-05 -5.275e-06  3.337e-06  7.596e-06  1.897e-05 

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)    
working_xjterm_f 1.2001391  0.0003452 3476.547   <2e-16 ***
working_xj       0.0000658  0.0002888    0.228    0.821    
working_xj       0.8994978  0.0014870  604.920   <2e-16 ***
```

And the coefficients fitted by `glmnet`:

```
# fit$beta
3 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
               s0
term_f  1.4736546
        0.2163814
       -0.2560925
```

As you can see from above, two fitted results are not alike. (This regression is a part of a bigger algorithm. In terms of the result of my whole algorithm, linear regression gives better estimation because the true coefficients is c(1.2, 0, 0.9))

From my perspective, in the ideal case the two fitting should give exactly the same coefficients because they have the same objective function. The correlation matrix of the design `X` may give some clue about this weird result:

```
# dim(X) is c(50, 3)
# length*y) is 50
# print(cor(X))
          [,1]      [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 1.0000000 0.9619002 0.994115
[2,] 0.9619002 1.0000000 0.985752
[3,] 0.9941150 0.9857520 1.000000
```

Columns of `X` are highly correlated, which may cause problems in regression. But I have no idea how everything happens or how to dig further into this problem.

Comment: Probably there is indeed too little variance in your data. Didn't you get a warning `essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable` in `lm`? Anyway, your question is mainly statistical and better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74206/ridge-regression-results-different-in-using-lm-ridge-and-glmnet